# Listbox in a Viewbox ListboxVerticalScrollbar doesn´t work

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, scrollbar, viewbox

I have a Listbox in a Viewbox.

```
<ViewBox>
...
<ListBox
                x:Name="ListBoxEmp"
                Width="620"
                Margin="20,0,0,0"
                Padding="0,0,0,0"
                DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Emp}"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmp, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="viewModels:EmpViewModel">
                        <DockPanel>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock>
                                    <Run Text="{Binding Lastname}" />
                                    <Run Text="{Binding Firstname}" />
                                </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock>
                                    <Run Text="{Binding Email}" />
                                </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tele}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
...
</ViewBox>
```

Whenever I add a new object to the list, the content of the entire window becomes smaller because of the Viewbox I guess. Is there a way to stop the reduction and add a scrollbar to the list box.

I need the Viewbox to proportionally resize the content of the window if the size changes of the window. This is why I am using it.

Thank you

Comment: Set the ListBox's MaxHeight or Height - as you are already setting its Width.

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately that didn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ViewBox>
<ContentControl>
    <ListBox.........>
         .............
    </ListBox>
</ContentControl>
</ViewBox>
```